# Cable size for 3-Phase 800 Amp

Tags: cables, three-phase

On a 800 AMP heating unit that is fed from 480VAC, 3 phase power. Will each conductor pull 800A or 266A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three phase loads are normally balanced to have the same current in each phase and normally specified by stating the current in one phase. So an 800 amp heating unit would have 800 amps in each supply conductor.

Comment: AC though, so is that a peak rating or a continuous rating?

Comment: It will be the RMS. The convention is RMS unless indicated